# R scraping when SelectorGadget cannot find valid paths

Tags: r, web-scraping

I tried to scrape the data for each country from interactive pie charts here: https://transparencyreport.google.com/eu-privacy/overview?site_types=start:1453420800000;end:1633219199999;country:&lu=site_types

But Selector Gadget does not allow me to select the data points on pie charts. How do I resolve this?

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
link = "https://transparencyreport.google.com/eu-privacy/overview?site_types=start:1453420800000;end:1633219199999;country:&lu=site_types"
page = read_html(link)
percentage = page %>% html_nodes("#content_types div") %>% html_text()
```

`"#content_types div"` returns void.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the page and look on the "Network" tab, you can see the api call being made to get the data.
The end number is the last millisecond of today.
There is some junk at the beginning, but the rest of the response is JSON.
You'll have to figure out what the category numbers mean.
Maybe there is documentation of the api somewhere.

```
library(magrittr)
link <- "https://transparencyreport.google.com/transparencyreport/api/v3/"
parms <- paste0("europeanprivacy/siteinfo/urlsbycontenttype?start=1453420800000&end=", 
                1000 * ((Sys.Date() + 1) %>% as.POSIXct() %>% as.numeric()) - 1)
page <- httr::GET(paste0(link, parms))
data <- page %>% httr::content(as = "text") %>% 
  substr(., regexpr("\\[\\[.*\\]\\]", .), .Machine$integer.max) %>% 
  jsonlite::fromJSON() %>% .[[1]] %>% .[[2]] %>% as.data.frame()
```